# Calculate differences in rows in r

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the differences of rows.
I get the error : replacement has 1818 rows, data has 1819

which makes sense for me. I have to find a solution how to tell R that the first observation in my row does not need to be calculated and just pass a 0 in it.
How can i do this.

Cheers

Comment: `c(0, diff(x, y))`

Comment: awesome. that was fast :)